# Is it possible to decorate more than once in Sitemesh?

Tags: layout, sitemesh

I'm trying to do something like this:
[image: the layout]

For all the requests to /admin/* I need the page to be decorated using the B decorator but also that B decorator has to be included in the content of A decorator which is main application layout.

How can I do that with Sitemesh?

Is it even possible? Or do I have to repeat the same layout from A in the B decorator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer my own question. Yes it is possible:

Using my own example, this is decorator **b** being decorated by decorator **a**.

```
<page:applyDecorator name="a">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Decorator B</title>
    <decorator:head/>
</head>
<body id="page-home">
    This is a test.
</body>
</html>
</page:applyDecorator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example using freemarker:

```
<#assign decorator = JspTaglibs["http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator"]/>
<#assign page = JspTaglibs["http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/page"]/>
<@page.applyDecorator name="a">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Decorator B</title>
    <@decorator.head/>
</head>
<body id="page-home">
    This is a test.
</body>
</html>
</@page.applyDecorator>
```