# Multiple body tags in Sitemesh 3

Tags: java, freemarker, sitemesh

I have been using Sitemesh 3 for my project and so far it's been working great. Recently I came across a situation where I am stuck.

My final view has to be composed of 2 html files, both have their own  and  tags.
File1:

```
<html>
    <head>Head1</head>
    <body>body1</body>
</html>
```

File2:

```
<html>
    <head>Head2</head>
    <body>body2</body>
</html>
```

I am composing a view using freemarker include tag. So, the composed HTML looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>Head1</head>
    <body>body1</body>
</html>
<html>
    <head>Head2</head>
    <body>body2</body>
</html>
```

Following is my decorator:

```
<html>
<head>
    <sitemesh:write property='head'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <sitemesh:write property='body'/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But once decorated, the final output I am getting is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <head>Head1</head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <body>body1</body>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the expected output is

```
<html>
<head>
    <head>
        Head1
        Head2
    </head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            body1
            body2
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I came across a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329693/is-it-possible-to-decorate-more-than-once-in-sitemesh), but that solution won't work for me because I don't want to create multiple decorators.

I just want to know if it's possible in Sitemesh 3. If yes, then how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind extending Sitemesh 3 then this is fairly easy to do by adding support for server side includes in your decorator template. I do exactly this in another library ([UtterlyIdle](http://code.google.com/p/utterlyidle/)).

I'm using StringTemplate as my decorator language but this should work in Freemarker or any other templating tool. I add in a [PageMap](http://code.google.com/p/utterlyidle/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/utterlyidle/sitemesh/PageMap.java) and then in my decorator template call

```
$include("someUrl").body$
```

This does a include and then parses the output with the Sitemesh 3 engine. This allows you to have as many includes as you like.

Hope that makes sense

Comment: Though this is not exactly the answer, it is an alternative. So, accepting it as an answer. :) Thanks.